# Transferring variable labels to variable values in SPSS/Python

Tags: python, datetime, variables, label, spss

I have a database (300 variables, 4000 cases) with lots of date/time variables. I imported into SPSS from Excel and used autorecode on all my variables but the variable LABELS contain the date/time information and the variable VALUES are all the default "October 14, 1582".

Is there an easy way either in SPSS or using Python to copy the variable labels over to the variable values? Is there a way I can only do this to some of my variables (eg., up to a certain point in the index?)

Many thanks! Mat.

Comment: please add some data and label samples

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the bigger problem is that e values are all wrong.  But I'm not clear on what you want to do from here.  Can you post an example?